# Proving "If $m >0$ and $ax+by=m$, then minimum value of $x^n+y^n$ occurs when we have$\frac{x^{n-1}}a=\frac{y^{n-1}}b$"

Tags: calculus, optimization

The textbook that I'm reading says,

> If $m >0$ and $ax+by=m$, then minimum value of $x^n+y^n$ occurs when we have$\dfrac{x^{n-1}}a=\dfrac{y^{n-1}}b$.

I'm wondering how we can prove this. It didn't specified the values of $n$ but I think it is true for $n=2,3,4\dots$. For $n=2$ It is easy to show this by Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality but I don't know how to prove this in general.

I also noticed that $x^n+y^n=ax(\dfrac{x^{n-1}}a)+by(\dfrac{y^{n-1}}b)$ but can't see how this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is elementary calculus. For minimizing $f(x)=x^n+y^n$ where $y$ is a function of $x$, we set $f’(x)=0$ which gives us $$nx^{n-1}+ny^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$ or $$x^{n-1}+y^{n-1}\frac{dy}{dx}=0.$$

But from the first equation, $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac ab$. This immediately gives the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

By the method of [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), at a minimum value of $f$ on a surface, the gradient of $f$ has to be normal to the surface.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, may be simpler to go by direct route. Assuming $b \ne 0$, you have $y = (m-ax)/b$, so let $b^{-n} = B$, you seek to minimize
$$
f(x) = x^n + \left(\frac{m-ax}{b}\right)^n = x^n + B(m-ax)^n,
$$
which you can do analytically...

Answer (score 1):

Lagrange multipliers! If you don't know about Lagrange multipliers look it up somewhere. The minimum of $f(x,y)=x^n+y^n$ subject to $g=ax+by$ occurs at a point where the two gradients are parallel: $$\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g,$$or $$(nx^{n-1},ny^{n-1})=\lambda(a,b),$$implying that $$\frac{x^{n-1}}a=\frac\lambda n=\frac{y^{n-1}}b.$$

Answer (score 1):

Just use Lagrange multipliers. Set $L=x^{n}+y^{n}-\lambda\,(ax+by-m)$.

Then $\dfrac{\partial\,L}{\partial\,x}=nx^{n-1}-\lambda\,a=0$

$\dfrac{\partial\,L}{\partial\,y}=ny^{n-1}-\lambda\,b=0$. By elimination of $\lambda$ we get:

$nx^{n-1}-ny^{n-1}\dfrac{a}{b}=0$ which gives :

$\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{a}=\dfrac{y^{n-1}}{b}$